# Problems with ": " in Ubuntu 16.04

Tags: keyboard-layout

I installed Ubuntu 15.x and my keyboard doesnt work well.

The <kbd>></kbd> key didn't work on terminal, browser... anywhere! (the <kbd><</kbd> worked well).
If I press CTRL+ALT+F1 and open the terminal-mode, then everything was OK.

NOW I updated to 16.04 version. The <kbd>></kbd> key works fine, but the <kbd>:</kbd> doesn't work anymore.

I tried to change the layout but nothing. I tried to reinstall the keyboard and still nothing.

How can I fix that?